# OpenStack Mitaka: command line client takes a long time to respond

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I've been using OpenStack on and off for a while now. After about a year I installed Mitaka (with keystone+swift) and noticed that the `openstack` command (CLI client), as well as the `swift` command are taking a really long time to respond - like 5 or 7 seconds. It didn't use to be like that.

Has there been a significant change in the design that is causing this issue? Maybe something wrong with my setup? Or any thoughts to debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to debug this is using curl do check if it's something on keystone(?), swift, your machine or the openstack client.

Since I didn't say which authentication method you are using, I will recommend this awesome post from Swiftstack to help you to authenticate:

https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/cookbooks/swift_usage/auth.html

If you get more info, it's going to be easy to find your bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks Nelson. `curl` actually took just as long to get the answer back, which led me to realize that the server was overloaded. Adding more CPU and RAM solved the problem.